# ckfinder ImagePreview vs Thubnail

Tags: ckfinder, ckfinder3

I've been banging my head for hours now, and hope someone had come across this problem and will be able to help me.

CKFinder doesn't show thumb images :(

When I get a list of images in a folder thumb images do not show but if I preview an image it works

Here it is an example, this is a preview URL which returns an image

http://localhost:12345/ckfinder/connector?command=ImagePreview&lang=en&type=Documents&currentFolder=%2Flogos%2F&hash=fdfe49e3ec5268debd763cc253c28db3f7642de7&folderId=Sponsors&fileName=e0523dee83c04e3d82701b496455b086%20(1).png&size=760x569&date=20200605083700

this is a thumb URL of the same image

http://localhost:12345/ckfinder/connector?command=Thumbnail&lang=en&type=Documents&currentFolder=%2Flogos%2F&hash=fdfe49e3ec5268debd763cc253c28db3f7642de7&folderId=Sponsors&fileName=e0523dee83c04e3d82701b496455b086%20(1).png&size=760x569&date=20200605083700

the only difference is in the command bit ImagePreview vs Thumbnail

If I call the above URL I get

```
// http://localhost:12345/ckfinder/connector?command=Thumbnail&lang=en&type=Documents&currentFolder=%2Flogos%2F&hash=fdfe49e3ec5268debd763cc253c28db3f7642de7&folderId=Sponsors&fileName=e0523dee83c04e3d82701b496455b086%20(1).png&size=760x569&date=20200605083700

{
  "error": {
    "number": 117,
    "message": "File not found. Please refresh the files list and try again."
  },
  "currentFolder": {
    "path": "/logos/",
    "acl": 1023,
    "url": "http://cdn.xyzxxxx.xxxxx/uploads/Sponsors/logos/"
  },
  "resourceType": "Documents"
}
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?